# Called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c++, algorithm, debugging, edit-distance

I am kinda new to C++, therefore, I don't know what is the cause of this error, I am trying to solve the [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) problem recursively, however, this error shows up.

> error: called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer
> return __comp(__b, __a) ? __b : __a;

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int distance(string, string, int, int);
int cost(string, string, int, int);
int main(){
    string v = "love";
    string v2 = "hate";
    cout<<distance(v, v2, v.size()-1, v2.size()-1);

    
}

int distance(string v, string v2, int a, int b)
{
    if (a==0) return b;
    if (b==0) return a;

    return min(
        distance(v, v2, a, b-1)+1,
        distance(v, v2,  a-1, b)+1,
        distance(v, v2, a-1, b-1)+cost(v, v2, a, b));

}
int cost(string v, string v1, int a, int b)
{
    if (v[a]==v1[b]) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `std::min(a, b, c)` -> `std::min({a, b, c})`.

Comment: BTW, also don't forget to include `<algorithm>` if you're going to use `std::min(...)`.

Comment: I recommend writing `using std::min;` rather than `using namespace std;`. See also [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: [OT]: pass your (unmodified) string by const reference instead of by value to avoid unneeded copies.

Comment: Programming by guessing language rules is not a good idea. Why do you think `min(a, b, c)` should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3rd argument of [`std::min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) is the comparer, you might prefer the overload taking initializer_list:

```
return min({
        distance(v, v2, a, b - 1) + 1,
        distance(v, v2,  a - 1, b) + 1,
        distance(v, v2, a - 1, b - 1) + cost(v, v2, a, b)});
```

Comment: Or call min twice: `return min(distance(v, v2, a, b-1)+1, min(distance(v, v2,  a-1, b)+1, distance(v, v2, a - 1, b - 1) + cost(v, v2, a, b)))`

Comment: @Stef: It is less clear IMO, so unless OP has to work pre-C++11, I won't use that.